# Why is Julia slow when decoding GZIP and parsing JSON?

Tags: python, benchmarking, julia

The following script reads the gzip file line-by-line and decodes JSON object

```
Pkg.add("GZip")
Pkg.add("JSON")


using GZip
using JSON

stream = GZip.gzopen(Base.ARGS[1])

_started = time()

i = 0

for line in eachline(stream)
    _j = JSON.parse(line)

    if i % 10000 == 0
        println(time()-_started)
    end

    i += 1

    try
        key_id = _j["some_id"]
    except
        pass
    end
end
```

output:

```
0.7071459293365479
20.09155511856079
37.8870849609375
```

compare to Python:

```
import os
import sys
import gzip
import datetime

import ujson as json

_started = datetime.datetime.now()

fh = gzip.open(sys.argv[1])
for i, line in enumerate(fh):

    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print datetime.datetime.now() - _started

    line = json.loads(line)
    try:
        k = line['some_id']
    except:
        pass
```

output:

```
0:00:00.028951
0:00:01.934277
0:00:03.821954
0:00:05.713572
```

Yes, I know, I used ujson which is really fast - but shouldn't Julia be faster anyway? Instead, it's much slower =(

P.S. Tried many times so it's not related to the OS cache or whatever.

P.P.S. Mac OS 10.7.3, Julia 0.2.1

Comment: Is the platform and version important? Usually for perf questions you'd want to be precise about the hardware and software used for your timings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, just forgot to add it. Mac OS 10.7.3. Julia 0.2.1.

Comment: Is it the GZIP or the JSON that is slow? Ought to be simple enough to isolate it to one or the other, or both.

Answer (score 5):

Isolating the JSON and GZIP operations is a good suggestion. My guess (only a guess!) is that most of the time is in JSON parsing; ujson is indeed very fast. There's no way to guarantee that everything that happens in a language is fast. PyPy, for example, will generally speed up python code a lot, but in some cases is still slow, or slower than C extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your computation in a function. Global variables are a known performance gotcha:

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/performance-tips/